# Reference to an item in CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have multiple different "item" classes in my HTML. Now I want to style my "item" separately for each of my two category ID´s, but somehow all "item" gets the same CSS applied. I tried different classes and different ID´s but nothing works. All my "item"s have the "loaded-layout"(=ID) CSS styling.

```
<div class="base-container">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-articles">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"></div>

                    <div class="item"></div>

                    <div class="item"></div>

                    <div class="item"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And:

```
<div class="masonry" id="loaded-layout">
     <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="well"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="well"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="well"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My CSS:

```
#loaded-layout.item {
    width:350px;
    height:auto;
    font-size:11px
}

#carousel-articles.item {
color:#01DF01;
background:#01DF01
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between those selectors because you're looking for a **child** with the class `item`, otherwise it's looking for an `.item` with an ID of `loaded-layout` or `carousel-articles`:

```
#loaded-layout .item {
    width:350px;
    height:auto;
    font-size:11px
}

#carousel-articles .item {
    color:#01DF01;
    background:#01DF01
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes I made mistake there, but somehow it didnt change anything. I now have NO styling anywhere. Its a Bootstrap3 template with Javascript for the loaded-layout. I am stumped really.

Comment: @RonBon Are you sure you didn't make a typo or something in the CSS file? Check the console to see what errors are shown when you load the page, that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: yes, I made a silly typo, all is good, works perfectly. thanks again!

Comment: @RonBon No probs glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#loaded-layout .item {
    width:350px;
    height:auto;
    font-size:11px
}

#carousel-articles .item {
color:#01DF01;
background:#01DF01
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k52eerfv/